# SQL Server 2012: Restoring split backup of a Filestream enabled database from a different server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, backup, restore

I have a split backup of a FileStream enabled database 'At' spread across 4 drives L,M,O,X in the 'prd' server that I want to restore to the 'crt' server. Both the servers are of 2012 version. I am using the below T-SQL in the crt server to restore a split backup from the prd server:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [At] FROM 
DISK = '\\prd\L\sql_bak\At_group1.bak', 
DISK = '\\prd\M\sql_bak\At_group2.bak', 
DISK = '\\prd\O\sql_bak\At_group3.bak', 
DISK = '\\prd\X\sql_bak\At_group4.bak' 
WITH REPLACE, NORECOVERY, STATS=20,
MOVE N'\\prd\E\sql_dat\At' TO N'\\crt\F:\sql_dat\At.mdf',
MOVE N'\\prd\D\sql_log\At_log' TO N'D:\sql_log\At_log.ldf',
MOVE N'\\prd\F\sql_dat\At_FS' TO N'I:\sql_dat\At_FS',
MOVE N'\\prd\I\sql_dat\At_FS2' TO N'J:\sql_dat\At_FS2',
MOVE N'\\prd\J\sql_dat\At_FS3' TO N'L:\sql_dat\At_FS3',
MOVE N'\\prd\N\sql_dat\At_FS4' TO N'O:\sql_dat\At_FS4',
MOVE N'\\prd\K\sql_dat\At_FS5' TO N'N:\sql_dat\At_FS5',
MOVE N'\\prd\R\sql_dat\At_FS6' TO N'K:\sql_dat\At_FS6',
MOVE N'\\prd\P\sql_dat\At_FS7' TO N'P:\sql_dat\At_FS7',
MOVE N'\\prd\F\sql_dat\At_FS8' TO N'I:\sql_dat\At_FS8',
MOVE N'\\prd\P\sql_dat\At_FS9' TO N'P:\sql_dat\At_FS9',
MOVE N'\\prd\F\sql_dat\At_FS10' TO N'I:\sql_dat\At_FS10',
MOVE N'\\prd\P\sql_dat\At_FS11' TO N'P:\sql_dat\At_FS11',
MOVE N'\\prd\P\sql_dat\At_FS12' TO N'P:\sql_dat\At_FS12',
MOVE N'\\prd\P\sql_dat\At_FS13' TO N'P:\sql_dat\At_FS13',
MOVE N'\\prd\P\sql_dat\At_FS14' TO N'P:\sql_dat\At_FS14',
MOVE N'\\prd\F\sql_dat\At_FS15' TO N'I:\sql_dat\At_FS15',
MOVE N'\\prd\F\sql_dat\At_FS16' TO N'I:\sql_dat\At_FS16',
MOVE N'\\prd\F\sql_dat\At_FS17' TO N'I:\sql_dat\At_FS17',
MOVE N'\\prd\F\sql_dat\At_FS18' TO N'I:\sql_dat\At_FS18',
MOVE N'\\prd\F\sql_dat\At_FS19' TO N'I:\sql_dat\At_FS19',
MOVE N'\\prd\I\sql_dat\At_FS20' TO N'J:\sql_dat\At_FS20',
MOVE N'\\prd\I\sql_dat\At_FS21' TO N'J:\sql_dat\At_FS21',
MOVE N'\\prd\I\sql_dat\At_FS22' TO N'J:\sql_dat\At_FS22',
MOVE N'\\prd\I\sql_dat\At_FS23' TO N'J:\sql_dat\At_FS23',
MOVE N'\\prd\I\sql_dat\At_FS24' TO N'J:\sql_dat\At_FS24',
MOVE N'\\prd\I\sql_dat\At_FS25' TO N'J:\sql_dat\At_FS25',
MOVE N'\\prd\N\sql_dat\At_FS26' TO N'O:\sql_dat\At_FS26',
MOVE N'\\prd\N\sql_dat\At_FS27' TO N'O:\sql_dat\At_FS27',
MOVE N'\\prd\N\sql_dat\At_FS28' TO N'O:\sql_dat\At_FS28',
MOVE N'\\prd\R\sql_dat\At_FS29' TO N'K:\sql_dat\At_FS29',
MOVE N'\\prd\U\sql_dat\At_FS30' TO N'K:\sql_dat\At_FS30',
MOVE N'\\prd\J\sql_dat\At_FS31' TO N'L:\sql_dat\At_FS31',
MOVE N'\\prd\K\sql_dat\At_FS32' TO N'N:\sql_dat\At_FS32',
MOVE N'\\prd\T\sql_dat\At_FS33' TO N'K:\sql_dat\At_FS33',
MOVE N'\\prd\V\sql_dat\At_FS34' TO N'K:\sql_dat\At_FS34',
MOVE N'\\prd\W\sql_dat\At_FS35' TO N'K:\sql_dat\At_FS35';
```

I am receiving this error:

> Msg 3231, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The media loaded on "\\prd\L\sql_bak\At_group1.bak" is formatted to
>   support 1 media families, but 4 media families are expected according
>   to the backup device specification.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally.

I have also verified the backup on crt:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK='\\prd\L\sql_bak\At_group1.bak'
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK='\\prd\M\sql_bak\At_group2.bak'
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK='\\prd\O\sql_bak\At_group3.bak'
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK='\\prd\X\sql_bak\At_group4.bak'
```

The parameter IsDamaged=0

The logical name was giving the same error that is why I tried using the location of the filename instead. 
This is not a normal restore.It is a restore of filestream enabled database from one server to another using split backup. 
These are the filestream files and these do not have any extensions. 
Please suggest.

Comment: Are you sure `At_group1.bak` is a split backup? The message seems to indicate otherwise. Maybe you can post the header and filelist here.

Comment: The move sources seem not right. There should not be path's but logical file names. I doubt this causes this specific error, though.